# css max-width is not working

Tags: html, css

I have parent element `width:100px` and `position:relative`. And I have its inner element with `position:absolute`. I need this inner element to stretch out up to 200px, but it doesn't work. Maximum value it takes is 100% of parent.

**UPD**
I don't want width to be fixed. I just needed it to be up to `200px` if there is content and `auto` if not much content there.

p.s. I need those `position` properties

Here's html:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div>element</div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

styling:

```
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted grey;   
}
```

And [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy6g2q7b/) to the example

Anyone please help

Comment: `max-width` is not the problem here – that property _is_ working, because your element does not get wider than 200px. The problem is how the width for absolutely positioned elements is calculated. If you want it to be wider, then you have to specify a `width` (or use `left` and `right` together.)

Comment: @CBroe yes, you are right. It's not getting more than 200 :) I just needed it to be wider up to 200px if there is content there and auto if not much content there. But thanks for help

Comment: You can not easily get “up to 200px if there is content there” with CSS under these circumstances; you would first of all make your content _take_ that kind of width, which it currently doesn’t, because it can break onto a new line after each “text”. If you don’t want that to happen, then you have to structure and/or format your content in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for help. Will try different way

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine. Your maximum width allowed is 200 pixels. See it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jy6g2q7b/1/

Maybe you are searching only for `width` (is fixed)

```
 .inner { width: 200px; }
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jy6g2q7b/4/

Comment: I don't want width to be fixed. I just needed it to be wider up to 200px if there is content there and auto if not much content there.  But thanks for help

Comment: So your code is that is working. http://jsfiddle.net/jy6g2q7b/1/ in this fiddle that I've created, you can view that inner sets with 200px when the content is bigger, and if you remove the content, the width is auto

Comment: yes. It works with textx but it doesn't work with my kind of content (those blocks)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I see that is working fine, if your content is an image maybe you need to apply styles to img.

Comment: this is my content: `<div class="item">text</div>`

Comment: Your code works fine with it. I don't know what are you searching. I believe that the other users that answer you feeling the same.

Comment: I cannot put just text inside `.inner` like you did. Inside `.inner` I can have only some number of `<div class="item">text</div>` elements. So it doesn't work with those elements. Width is not getting wider that 100px

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I think the problem is that with floated content the `max-width` value of `.inner` is not reached because it is limited by the `width` value of `.parent`. In the example supplied the OP wants the red box to exceed the width of the yellow box.

Comment: @Matiishyn I don't put text inside `.inner`, see that I put the text in `.item`. I don't understand what's the problem. So sorry :(

Comment: Oh! I think that I understand now. I go to research

Comment: I think that if your `.inner` is a child of `.parent` is impossible to reach that you like. If the box is out of `.parent` is easiest to achieve.

Comment: well, I'm getting similar decision.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. The `max-width` value of `.inner` is not reached because it is limited by the `width` of `.parent` and the `float`ed `.item`s will only be on the same row until they hit the right edge of the containing element.

One way around this issue is to use a pseudo element to achieve a similar bordered result without the restrictive `width`:

- Remove `width` from `.parent`, this will cause it to take up `100%` of the `width` as it is a `block` level element. Remove `border: 1px solid yellow;` as it will no longer have the desired result
- Create a new pseudo element `.parent:before`. Set `border: 1px solid yellow;` and `width: 100px;` to show the yellow border on this instead
- Set `.parent:before` to be `position: absolute;` and have `height: 100%;` to position it relatively `.parent` and get it to fill the correct area

Now that `.inner` is not restricted by the `width` of `.parent` it should abide by the `max-width: 200px;` rule.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.parent:before {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.item {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>element</div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
    <div class="item">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add "`width: 200%`" to the `.inner` and the `max-width` will still work.

```
.inner {
    width: 200%;
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jy6g2q7b/2/

Comment: I don't want width to be fixed. I just needed it to be wider up to 200px if there is content there and auto if not much content there.  But thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AngularJS, you can use `ng-style = {'width':'200%'}`. And if not, you can change it to inherit from parent `

```
.inner {
    max-width: inherit;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I don't want width to be fixed. I just needed it to be wider up to 200px if there is content there and auto if not much content there.  But thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

All that problem (odd behavior) is occurring due to this line -

```
.item {
    float: left; /* THIS ONE */
    border: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

you need to find some other alternative for those text blocks to align. You can use `display: table-cell` instead of `float`, but that makes the blocks go out of `#content`

I'll update my answer if I find any alternative.

Comment: hm. Well `float: left;` is not important for me. I've also tried `display:flex`. But with `display: table-cell` I can only have one line. And I need it to become 2 lines when content is bigger

Comment: @Matiishyn `display: table-cell` works well but there is only one defect, the text blocks will not wrap to next line.

Comment: @Matiishyn sorry for my half comment. actually, if you can add a `<br />` to break them to next line (after some no. of blocks insert `<br />`),

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:static` for the parent and then try

```
.parent {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    position: static;
    width: 100px;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: as I wrote in my question I need those `position` properties set up like that. `relative` for parent. But thanks for answer